# How to sync PouchDB between devices over Wi-Fi?

Tags: cordova, p2p, pouchdb

We are looking into using PouchDB between devices that could sync up together over Wi-Fi.

Think of multiple mobile devices (phones and tablets) that each have a local PouchDB instance and each of them are making their own set of changes to the database. Then, following some business rule, they want to sync up with other devices.

We still have to look into the device discovery via Phonegap apps, so any help on this would be appreciated. But, let's say Device A found the IP of Device B and device B exposes itself on a specific port.

Could we just use PouchDB to sync both devices like so:

`PouchDB.sync('deviceA_DB', 'http://123.45.56.78:5984/deviceB_DB');`

(where 123.45.56.78 is the local IP of Device B)

Or am I missing something big in this plan?

Answer (score 3):

This is something I've been really interested in trying out, but never gotten around to implementing. :)

If you would like to be the first pioneer into this bold new territory of syncing PouchDB over wifi, then I would recommend starting with [pouchdb-replication-stream](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-replication-stream). Basically it decomposes PouchDB/CouchDB replication into a simple stream of newline-delimited JSON, so you can use any transport mechanism that supports sending plaintext from A to B.

However I'm not aware of any p2p wifi plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap, so you would probably need to write your own. Another option may be Bluetooth or WebRTC; for the latter, somebody has already started working on that: [PeerPouch](https://github.com/natevw/PeerPouch).

Hope that helps! Good luck.